# Using powershell, how do I extract the thumbprint from an SSL Certificate without installing it?

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate

Every example I've found on StackExchange, and other internet forums, etc all tell me how to get the thumbprint from a certificate already installed into a certificate store. Alternatively, the instructions say to install the cert, then get the thumbprint.

However, I really need to get the thumbprint from the pfx file *without* installing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get an object in Powershell-3.0 and later, which can then be used with `Select` and other property accessors:

```
 Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath Certificate.pfx
```

Alternatively, one can use `openssl` from msys or cygwin. However, this is tricky since it's one of those *nix programs that spews all the useful info to stderr, which gets handled badly in powershell.

```
 openssl pkcs12 -info -in Certificate.pfx
```

Note: Both of these methods require the user to input the password. I've yet to find a fully automated way to do this without manually entering the password each time.

Comment: There is an automated way of doing it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42570310/1563172

Answer (score 2):

Following on the previous answers to provide a complete and concise answer. This will print the given certificate's thumbprint:

```
(Get-PfxCertificate <certificate_path>).Thumbprint
```

It will interactively ask for the password of the certificate. Use @Zehad's method to provide the password non-interactively

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one . Will do everything with one command in powershell. Just set the path and Password

```
Get-PfxCertificate -Filepath "PATH OF THE FILE STORED" -Password ($pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PASSWORD" -Force -AsPlainText)
```